# VBScript Task scheduler not working?

Tags: vbscript, qlikview

I am trying to schedule a VBscript using windows task scheduler. It doesn't require any user interaction. It does open a qlikview application file and download some reports but no user interaction is needed.

It works fine when I run it manually, but the problem when I try to run it using task scheduler the qlikview application is not getting opened. But a process seems to be running in the background (I checked task manager).

I have scheduled a task like this 
:

**Start a Program** : C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe
**Arguments**: C:\Script_Location\Script.vbs

I have tried creating batch file and scheduling that. It didn't work out

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If your script launches an app that creates a window, it's interactive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the QlikView launched by the VbScript is looking for some user interaction, possibly licensing or database connection configuration. Check the Windows Event Application log for application pop-ups to see any pop-up messages the qv.exe may have displayed.